# Setting the decimal separator for CSV output in dbVisualizer

Tags: export-to-csv, dbvisualizer

Is there a way to set the decimal separator for the CSV output in dbVisualizer for each export separately?

I can set e.g. the encoding and the column delimiter using

```
@export set filename="t:\my.csv" Encoding="Cp1252" CsvColumnDelimiter=",";
```

but I cannot find a way to set the decimal separator for a specific csv export. I have found the global setting in the preferences however I need different formats for individual exports. Setting the DecimalFormat is unlikely helpful as the "." in the format refers to just the predefined decimal separator as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameters are used to specify grouping and decimal separators:

```
@export set NumberGroupingSeparator="," DecimalNumberSeparator=".";
```

The DbVisualizer [users guide](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG/@export+-+Export+query+result) will be updated to reflect this tomorrow.